# Toilet is refilling every few hours

Tags: plumbing

Our toilet is refilling every few hours. The bowl is dry, so its not leaking there. Plumber has been but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

If its every few hours, you probably won't see it on the bowl. Without actually seeing it, it is hard to give an accurate answer, but I would say the flapper needs replaced. If that's fine, then the rubber gasket under the flapper needs replaced. That's the normal issues and if it's the gasket, you won't really see it. It can be very very subtle.

Comment: You can add some food coloring to the tank and if the flapper/seal is leaking you'll be able to tell because the water in the bowl will be colored.